# How to use ATK namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm new in programming world and I need to use Microsoft Arabic Toolkit service (ATKS) namespace and its inner namespaces such as Parser and POSTagger. Microsoft ATKS namespace is found here

https://atks.microsoft.com/

I have an API but this still doesn't work? Do you know how could I do that? Please help me

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using ATK.Parser;

namespace ATK

{

class Program

{

static void Main(string[] args)

{

string AppID = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";

....
}}}

The parser couldn't be called and I can't use any method that it contains..

Comment: How it is not working? What error you are getting? Sharing more code would be helpful

Comment: I'd like to know how can I use it. I found the svc files but I still couldn't use the services. Is there any simple way to do that?